# How to Optimize in Error to create react-app?

Tags: reactjs, homebrew, macos-catalina

I'm getting this error when I run **npx creat-react-app**

```
@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@2.19.2: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^8.10.0 || ^10.13.0 || >=11.10.1". Got "10.11.0
```

*brew is not work in MacOs Catalina*
how i fix it ?

Comment: what do node -v and npm -v say?

Comment: "brew is not work in MacOs Catalina" what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error your node version is `10.11.0`, while create-react-app requires a version above or equal `10.13.0`.

To fix it, update your node version ([download here](https://nodejs.org/)). Probably there are some known issues with yours when using CRA.

Answer (score 0):

Just like @matthiasgiger has already mentioned you need to visit:

https://nodejs.org/en/

And download the latest version of Node. Currently 12.16.1 LTS is the version that is recommended for most users. After successful download open the file and follow the prompts from the install wizard.